# Cant catch ConstraintViolationException on entity delete

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem deleting an entity that have some related data.
When i call the repository delete method in my service I have this exception:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "table" violates foreign key constraint...
The code is something like this:

```
@Transactional
public void delete(Long id) {
    Entity entity = repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(()->new Exception("not found"));
    try {
       repository.delete(entity);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem is that this exception isn't caught by the catch block even if I try to catch Throwable or ConstraintViolationException.
Why is this not working? Is it possible to do what I want?

Thanks

Comment: Why would delete throw an exception if findById finds it?

Comment: In case the entity have some related entities It can throw DataIntegrityViolationException

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to JPAs write behind cache. JPA gathers all the changes you make to your entities and tries to execute them as late as possible against the database.

In your case the execution happens when the transaction is committed, which is after you left the try catch block.

The easiest way to fix this is to add a `repository.flush` after the `repository.delete`.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove it directly with the id, you don't need to find it before. Try to catch a `DataIntegrityViolationException` if it is possible that it have foreign constraints.

Comment: Hi, I'm using the find to throw a custom exception if the the entity does not exist.
In my true code I don't call direct the find but I call a utility method that throw a custom exception. Is't it a good idea?

Comment: Hi, yes, if you want to throw the exception.